# Strange CE Image / Stash / Low Search problem

Tags: stash, low-search, ce-image

I have a strange problem where a CE Image tag is outputting fine for one Stash list but not another but only when within a Low Search results tag, works fine in a normal channel entries tag.

**APPEND LIST**

```
{product_styles search:code="not IS_EMPTY"}
  {exp:stash:append_list
    name="product_images_{entry_id}"
  }
    {stash:product_lg}
    <img src="{exp:ce_img:single
      src='{image}'
      width='350'
      height='350'
      crop='yes'
      quality='85'
      url_only='yes'
      allow_scale_larger='yes'
      interlace='yes'}">
    {/stash:product_lg}
    {stash:product_options}
      <option
        value="{title} {code}"
        data-thumb="{exp:ce_img:single
          src='{image}'
          width='50'
          height='50'
          crop='yes'
          quality='85'
          url_only='yes'
          interlace='yes'}"
      >{code} {title}</option>
    {/stash:product_options}
  {/exp:stash:append_list}
{/product_styles}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="product_images_{entry_id}"}
{product_lg}
{/exp:stash:get_list}

{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
  <select>
    {exp:stash:get_list name="product_images_{entry_id}"}
    {product_options}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
  </select>
{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

So with the above, I get a series of images output fine where `{product_lg}` is, but where `{product_options}` is, it's outputting `<option value="XXXXX" data-thumb="{exp:ce_img:single src='filename.jpg'… ">XXXXX</option>`, i.e. parsing the CE image tag inside the `option`.

Which I can't work out because it's essentially the same tag just with slightly different parameters. Anyone have any ideas what's going wrong? :?

Comment: Have you tried parameters for the append_list like parse_vars="yes" and parse_depth="2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the single tag form of `{exp:ce_img}`, and if you repeat an instance of a single tag in the same template EE will "cache" subsequent instances after parsing the first (replaces with a random-string marker, with the intention of replacing with the value at the end of parsing). You can either append the word `random` at the end of the ce_img tag parameters, or cause the image to be fully parsed when the list is appended by using `parse="yes"`.